# how to add double quotes between two variables in python

Tags: string, python-2.7

```
user=config.get("plugin_etc_passwd",'user')
host=config.get("plugin_etc_passwd",'host')
```

This are the two variable having my user and host
Now my problem is I need to turn this into command below.

```
command=["ssh", "tara@localhost", "cat","/etc/passwd"]
```

I have  tried following two ways but its not reading the variable value and just adding the quotes how do I achieve it.

```
command=["ssh", '"'user+'@'+host'"', "cat","/etc/passwd"]

command=["ssh", '"user"'+'@'+'"host"', "cat","/etc/passwd"]
```

Comment: `command=["ssh", "{user}@{host}".format(user=user, host=host), "cat","/etc/passwd"]`

Comment: I would make it a two-liner to make things clearer, with a line before it like `machine = "{user}@{host}".format(user=user, host=host)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try string formatting,

```
 command = ["ssh","%s@%s"%(user,host),"cat","/etc/pass"]
```